# Trying to solve CSS sidenote overlapping

Tags: html, css, overlap

I'm almost finished with a pretty big text project that I'm working on, and I need to address a problem I've been putting off: the sidenotes I'm using are occasionally running into each other and overlapping. You can see the problem [here](http://www.dinkypage.com/142503) if you look for `ovoce a` or `Euripedes`.

There are probably lots of different ways of solving the problem. But I'm just not sure where to begin. Any suggestions or clever ideas would be very welcome. Thanks!

EDIT: I'm trying this again. The solution that seemed to work turned out not to work too well!

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML structure, the asides belong to the same column as the main text. If you take away the asides' CSS, they will appear in their original positions, pushing the main text further down. The CSS pushes the asides to the left; `position:absolute` prevents the asides from taking up space in the main text's column. The layout relies heavily on `position:absolute`. Take the property out and all the numbering pseudo-elements in front of the paragraphs will be displaced as well.

To achieve the same effect without absolute positioning, you have to rewrite a lot of code: either introduce a 4-column (instead of 2-column) table and move the sidenotes to their own columns, or switch to a jungle of floated `div`s. Welcome to CSS hell.

I don't know how strict the restrictions on your project are, but here's another approach.

```
.sidenote {
    background-color: white;
}
.sidenote:hover {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

By setting `background-color` to white, the asides will be opaque. Should they overlap, the aside further down will cover the one above it. As soon as the user hovers over an aside, it will be brought on top of the nearby asides.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for ovoce and found the issue. The sidenote for the text above it is too long so it overlaps. Anyway you can just style the text below it and give it a margin-top like this?

```
style="margin-top: 60px;"
```

Comment: @ Sean Coker: I just gave it a quick try, and it seems to work! I wonder how much CSS I'll have to do before I actually understand CSS...

Comment: Oops, it looks like this technique simply scoots down the next sidenote, without any attempt to avoid the previous sidenote. Is there an alternative technique that occurs to you? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, as all of the sidenotes use `position:absolute`, there is no way the browser can determine if they overlap.

Comment: @JimmyX Is there a way to get the sidenotes to work without ``position:absolute``? Thanks.